# Why Microsoft includes group policies from old OS in new OS?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm currently on Windows 10 PRO and I see tons of policies in Local Group Policies Editor that apply only to Windows XP/Windows Server 2003. What is the reason to include them, if they have no effect on my OS?
Am I right in my assumption that this is for backwards comparability (e.g. to be able to join windows 2003 domain from Windows 10)?

Comment: Can you give us an example one or two of the policies you're talking about?

Comment: Perfect example is setting an active desktop (webpage as wallpaper). This was deprecated from Visa I think? But it's still in the GP editor...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Search\Do not allow web search - Requires Windows XP, or Windows Server 2003 with Windows Search version 3.01 or later  
User Configuration\Start Menu and Taskbar\Add Search Internet link to Start Meny - Requires Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7  
User Configuration\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove user name from Start Meny - Requires Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP only

Comment: My guess would be that it's simply because they use the same policy set they use for domain Group Policies (because that's easier than maintaining multiple policy sets).  When using Group Policies on a domain network, the server and/or workstation you're administering GP from needs all the polices for previous version of Windows in it still, as they can still be joined to the domain and controlled by group policies.  Having said that, I'm not convinced anyone can provide you with anything more concrete than guesses for answers (as we're not MS, it's hard to say _why_ they do anything).

Comment: Both those policies apply to "Windows XP ... or later" so while the feature might be depreciated the group policy had not been.